# $.extend(item,this.defaults) is working strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscript

I am just starting out with javascript, trying to modify code I found in a book.  `$.extend(item,this)` works just as I expect.  But when I replace with `$.extend(item,this.defaults)` it does not correctly extend the item. What do I need to change in my formatting to fix that?

```
function addItem(details){
    var item = {};
    var name = details.name;
    $.extend(item,this);

    alert ("attempted to add new default"+this.defaults.type);
    alert ("added default"+item.defaults.type);

    return item;
};
```

Comment: Please provide a working code example using the snippet tool (Ctrl+M).

Comment: You're going to have to tell us how that function is called, and what `this` is

Comment: Thank you @adeneo for asking about what "this" means.  It helped me to realize that $.extend(item,this)  and $.extend(item,this.defaults) are copying quite different sets of properties.  Thanks to both responders for answering a noob question.  I will try to provide more detail when I ask my next question.